# React element is incorrectly reporting width of the window

Tags: reactjs

I'm attaching a ref like this:

```
<div id="vis" ref={el => (this.vis = el)} />
```

And when I inspect the element after the page loads, it reports the correct width (it is width: 100% and its parent is max-width 1200px, so ends up being 1200px on a typical screen). However, `this.vis.clientWidth` or `this.vis.getBoundingClientReact().width` report the full window size, even if I put a setState in componentDidMount to trigger a rerender.

I'm trying to avoid using an npm module for this since it seems like it should be simple. Any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

Full code:

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    containerWidth: 0
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ containerWidth: this.vis.getBoundingClientRect().width });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.containerWidth);
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div id="vis" ref={el => (this.vis = el)} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  width: 80vw;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
}

#vis {
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: I think Dan Abramov showed an example of that in the video on https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.headerRef = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.headerRef.current.clientWidth); // will be 500 as set in CSS
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 id="vis" ref={this.headerRef}>
          Grab this element
        </h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

And the CSS:

```
#vis {
  width: 500px;
}
```

Live demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/5wqllzqv0x

Comment: This still isn't working for me unfortunately. The element correctly shows up as 500px in the browser, but the console.log prints the window's width.

Comment: @MatthewMasurka Not sure how that's possible... Just tried it and prints 500 for me in the console...

Comment: @SakuBu I appreciate that, but I copied & pasted your code and it's not working for me. I've tried multiple browsers, restarted the browser. Still no luck. Very strange.

Comment: @MatthewMasurka Strange indeed... Did you try the demo? You can open the (built in console) and it's there... Is that not showing up for you as well?

Comment: Yeah it's working there, but when I copy and paste those files and try locally, it doesn't work. I also just tried updating create-react-app, but still no luck.

Comment: Any other ideas?  I just tried react-measure, and it reports the correct width after a couple render cycles, however it made my app really janky (I'm building something in D3 with a lot of nodes).

Comment: @MatthewMasurka not really... I would need the entire codebsse to try ad make sense...